# Is it possible to have a vector pointing to a subset of other vector?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a two-dimensional wrapper around `std::vector` and would like to have a member returning a vector pointing to a subset of the class data vector e.g.

```
class matrix2D{
    // ...
   int nR, nC;
   std::vector<float> data;
   // ...
}

std::vector<float> matrix2D::row(int row){
    return std::vector(data.begin()+row*nCols,data.begin()+row*nCols+nCols);
}
```

EDIT: I was mostly interested in this in order to be able to modify an entire row (and column as well) in place e.g. `mat.row(r) = std::vector<float> (nR, 0.0)`;
I've written operator overloads that allow me to sum element-wise two matrix2D objects or a matrix2D and a scalar value, as well as an operator () overload that allows me to modify or access a particular matrix element in place i.e. `float& operator()(int _r, int _c)`;  The row method above returns a copy of the row data, and although inefficient, works from an access standpoint. I have also a `void setRow(std::vector<float> _row)` that modifies an entire row, but was wondering if there was an alternative way.

Comment: Nope. A `vector` always owns its data. You could maybe use `gsl::span` or roll your own equivalent memory view. Alternatively you could simply pass a `begin/end` pair of iterators around.

Comment: Are you sure a simple `float *operator[](size_t)` wouldn't do what you *need* (vs. want) ?

Comment: Just as an experiment, I tried [std::basic_string_view<float>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view).  To my surprise, it worked for the [small sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acd0554a2acb1ac1)

Comment: The point of the experiment is to see if you can get a "view into the vector" without copying.  Yes, you don't get all of the vector's member functions that add or remove values from the vector such as `push_back`, `erase`, etc., but you do get the usual iterators and other aspects that comes with views.

Comment: Maybe you want to write your own iterator class, having its own versions of operator++, operator+=, operator*, operator->, comparison, etc (have a look at std::vector so get an impression of what you need). E. g. operator++ could just increment if iterating over a row, but would add row length if iterating over a column or row length + 1 if iterating over a diagonal. You'd need a proper way to detect end of iteration as well, some end marker within your matrix class, maybe you can even re-use the vector's end iterator for.  You then might want to implement a const_iterator as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your class is a 2d matrix, you may want to be able to return a subset of the vector's data which isn't necessarily a sequential range in the vector.  For example you may want to return a single column of the matrix, even though it appears you are storing it in row-major order, or you may want to return diagonal elements of the matrix.  If this is the case, the solutions given in the comments (which suggest to return a pointer into the vector data, or to return a pair of iterators) won't work, since you would need to exclude certain elements among the range specified by those values.

If this is the case, one thing you could do is return a vector of `int`s which are indices into the matrice's `data` vector.  This vector of indices would be what you are looking for: a subset which does not necessarily appear sequentially in the `data` vector.

You could overload the `matrix2D`'s subscript operator to accept such a collection and return a special temporary type with assignment semantics for the subset of the `matrix2D`, so you could write code like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  matrix2d matrix4x4(4, 4);
  std::vector<float> values(4, 1);
  auto first_column = matrix4x4.first_column();

  matrix4x4[first_column] = values;
  matrix4x4.print();
  // output is:
  // 1 0 0 0
  // 1 0 0 0
  // 1 0 0 0
  // 1 0 0 0
}
```

That way you could not only access subsets of values in the matrix, but also modify the subset.

Here is a quick implementation of this idea which should demonstrate the above example: https://ideone.com/j5DfBg

Obviously you could make a lot of improvements on that design, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: This precisely what I was looking for! I had written `getcCol(int)` and `setCol(int _col)` methods for access and modification, but this allows me to use the same method, and in a much more memory efficient manner.

Comment: You can take this idea further and accept 2d collections of indices in the subscript operator to let you reshape matrices easily.  Also one last suggestion, make liberal use of `assert` to check that indices are in bounds, and that the shape and size of index collections, value collections, and the matrice's dimensions are compatible, to catch bugs early and make problems as obvious as possible.  That way it will be very clear to you what is going wrong if you try and do something like assign 5 values to a column of a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: As a further comment, if one just needs to access and modify rows or columns, then it would be possible to replace the `std::vector<int>` object with just a `int`, as it is straightforward to resolve the indices from the row/column number. However, an issue I'm having is how to access the data of a particular column e.g. `std::vector<float> matRow = matrix4x4[first_column]` does not work because the compiler does not know how to cast `subscript_return_type` into a `std::vector<float>`

Comment: Yes, you need to define implicit conversion semantics for the `subscript_return_type` to cast it to a `std::vector<float>`.  Check out: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: @joaocandre I made an example for you: https://ideone.com/fe6Otk.  You are interested in line 30.  This is an implicit conversion function, you can read more about it in the links I provided above.  This function is what implicitly casts the `subscript_return_type` to a `vector<float>` on line 85.

Comment: thanks for that, this is a level of C++ above my knowledge which I'm not familiar with, but from what I've gathered there is no need for move semantics in such a class right?

Comment: Not the class in the examples I posted, but I haven't seen your full class.  These two articles should answer most questions you could have on this topic: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor.  Specifically in the 'rule of three' article, you will be interested in the 'rule of five' section.

Comment: sorry to comment this late, but am I right to assume that directly returning an object of type `subscript_return_type` from your `firstColumn` method bypass the need of the `[]` operator and allow me to be able to write `matrix4x4.fisrtColumn()=std::vector<float> (4,0.0);` ???

Comment: Yes, you could do this.  If this is better or worse depends on your needs.  Check out how the matlab language is designed for ideas related to this (programming constructs for working with matrices and vectors)